# Google Drive showing device data without my consent

Tags: google-drive, synchronization, android

I signed in three Google accounts on my android phone.

In Google account synchronization settings, I unchecked Google Drive so that no data from Google Drive server synced to phone and no data from the phone should be saved on Google Drive server.

However, when I open Google Drive, I see phone data on Google Drive. As I said, three Google accounts are signed in an Android phone. It is picking any account’s Google Drive randomly.

I uninstalled Google Drive and re-installed it.

However, I see the same issue.

Comment: If this question is about the Google Drive app for Android, then it's off-topic on this site but it might be on-topic on [android.se]. If it's about using Google Drive on web browser,  please clarify.

Comment: Using Google Drive in Android Phone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using an Android app. Try [android.se].

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is just a way of letting files to be checked if they weren't updated. If they were updated to a more recent version (the same file just modified) then they will be picked up and replaced on all devices where you allowed synchronization.

In other words, you cannot have phone data on Drive and that Drive to be just a local phone version of a Drive.